# Mac Vanilla Menu Bar App - How can I move the icon around?

Tags: catalina, menu-bar, 3rd-party

[image: Menu Bar Picture]
This is my current menu bar. The little caret at the far left is the Vanilla app hiding some icons. Works great, but I want to move the caret all the way to the right. Is there a way to do that? Using command + drag is not working. 

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the command key and move the app around wherever you like!

*At least in my case. It may not work for you from your description.*